# How to Migrate Spring Batch Cron Jobs To Spring Cloud Task

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, quartz-scheduler, spring-cloud-task, kubernetes-cronjob

I used quartz api for existing cron jobs but how should I configure these cron jobs with spring cloud task. We can dynamically get the cron expression definitions for each job from the DB for schedule the job, but how I need to configure it with spring cloud task for each job.

I haven't seen a document about configuring more than one cron jobs for spring cloud task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Cloud Task isn't a replacement for Quartz or any scheduler API so that migration isn't functionally the same. You would still use Quartz with Spring Cloud Task to handle the orchestration (when to run the workload) just as you would with Spring Batch.

Comment: Thanks Michael for the answer. Can't we write cron jobs written with spring batch framework and quartz api libraries without using quartz api only with spring cloud task and spring batch framework?

Comment: Spring Batch and Spring Cloud Task do not provide scheduling APIs. You would need to use Quartz or Spring Framework’s scheduling capabilities to perform the actual scheduling or use a platform that has scheduling capabilities like Kubernetes.

Comment: Thanks Michael your answers have been very explanatory for me.